# SQL Server deadlock occurs when executing 2 application/instance simultaneously(Error code:1205)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, locking, deadlock, blocking

We have an application through which a large amount of string values (like 5000 character string- a column of datatype `nvarchar(MAX)`) is coming to a SQL  script.

The script has various transactions with 3 tables, where one of them is the master, another one is the history and the third is the LOG table. We are checking that the incoming string is present in master table or not; if it is not present in the master table, then we are inserting the values into master, history and log tables.

If it is present in the master table, then we are comparing the data with master; if there are any differences, then we update the master table, and insert the values into the history and log tables.

When we are executing 2 application/instance simultaneously, we are facing deadlock problem in the database. The error code we get from the application is 1205.

The error message is:

> Transaction (Process ID 75) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction

We cannot use begin and commit transaction in the script because this will make the process slower. So is there any way to solve this specific problem?

Comment: Please update your question with deadlock graph

Answer (score 0):

Check the execution plans to see if the queries can be optimized with query/index tuning to touch only those rows needed. If that's not possible (e.g. due to a full scan searching the `nvarchar(MAX)` value without additional criteria that can use index seeks), deadlocks cannot be avoided with the default READ_COMMITTED isolation level behavior.

Possible solutions:

- retry after a deadlock is encountered
- serialize the process with an exclusive lock on the master table or
  with [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql)
- use `SNAPSHOT` isolation so that row versioning instead of locking is
  used for consistency

I think `SNAPSHOT` isolation is the best solution here if the problem is inevitable due to full scans of the master table. In the event of concurrent processes updating the same row, you will get a concurrency error upon `COMMIT` and will need to retry.